# Are lost blueprints gone for good in Dead Cells?

Tags: dead-cells

One point in the game, after defeating the Concierge boss for the fifth time, I received the blueprint for Alienation, but then I spent all my cells at the legendary forge, so there was no reason for me to go to the collector I thought. In the next area I died, dropping my hard earned cells, but also the aforementioned blueprint, which I had forgotten to turn in. Do I lose that blueprint for good? Or will I just have to kill the boss again. This happened on August 9th on Xbox one, and it is the proper update version, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On PC at least, defeating the boss again will drop the same blueprint.
I've had this happen to me on an older build, so I wouldn't expect any problems on xbox.

Comment: @mmatyhews     I'm not going to confirm the answer just yet until I get back on and check it myself, but thank you very much for the help.